# place to propose a open source project and collaborate on software requirements before start to coding

Tags: open-source, startup, requirements, collaboration

I'm searching for a web site to start a new open source project.
I want to start the developing of a "SPORT training log".
I have some developing skill but not all I need (I dont know web coding).

Anyone know a good starting point to meet some people, propose the software and then (in another place also) start the development all together?

For example, I have python, c, c++ skills and a little training experience, but I want to make it in web, so I can't do all the stuff alone. I dont think I'm the only one who wants to make a training log but dont have necessary skills. I'm searching for a site to manage the idea behind a training log and get interested people to contribute in the idea and then eventualy contribute also in the code.

What I mean is a step before actualy FOSS approach.

The question is:

Why start to code software I need if I can start global software requirements about a "sport traning log" and after a useful and global review, we can start all together to developt it? Why should I need to start developing the software with XYZ features and other people who need features YZQ need to start to write another one? Why not put the opensource comunity a step before in a more professional way starting an opensource project with a collaborative approach also in software requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little of topic butr, hey maybe you have found something greater than your main goal. What if you digg a bit more on the "open source pre project site", i think that could be an amazing idea and would be more than exited to participate in.

As an enthuast on those matters, i would really like to have an open source place where you could share ideas and start projects in a collaborative way.

Like having open source intelectual right policy, so people could use those ideas to improve our every day internet experience without the fear of someone stealing whats yours.

Think about it!

Comment: i thinked about 'the greath idea behind it' and i think this idea can be a nice step to make more collaborative the growing of new FOSS software. it's a sort of software requirements specification collaborative. how many ppl have nice idea and dont have the skill to manage it or dont have other ppl to ask some help or otherwise how many ppl code is own software with feature X,Y,Z and similar project are started again from scratch with X,Q,T features wasting all together the same time! i'm searching on "open source pre project site" and i update here some stuff if you want!

Comment: That would be really amazing. When dealing with an application, feature request are gold, and deffinitly could define wether a project success of fails. Really looking forward to updates on the matter!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a site, and I would be very interested to know if anything like that exists.

But I guess your best bet is searching for which are already doing something similar and see if/how you could work together.

You could eg take pytrainer, which is not a web application but has done already quite a lot of thinking on presenting results, importing from devices/...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytrainer/

Or the other way around, search for logbook web software and adjust that for sports logging.